# Export/Import Azure API Management Developer Portal UI changes

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

I have made some UI changes on APIM developer portal.

Is there a way to export the UI changes that I have made and import those changes in some other developer portal?
Changes are only in UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Automated migration script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/automate-portal-deployments) `scripts.v3/migrate.js`.

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/blob/master/scripts.v3/migrate.js)

> **The script performs the following steps:**
> Capture the portal content and media from the source API Management service.
> Remove the portal content and media from the destination API Management service.
> Upload the portal content and media to the destination API Management service.
> Optionally and for managed portals only - automatically publish the portal.

[Tutorial: Migrating managed Developer portal between APIM services](https://dipolimene.medium.com/migrating-managed-developer-portal-between-apim-services-276ab981c1ab)